# android app runs perfectly when extracted as apk but doesnt creates error in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-camera

So I am creating and app that uses the camera API. The app is close to done it just needs to have a few more features added. However when I try to launch the app on the emulator or my phone from eclipse it creates a runtime error saying unable to resume activity: fail to connect to camera service. I have tried multiple emulators and yes the camera option is turned on. I am just so confused to why it runs perfect when exported as an apk and installed on my phone but doesnt work when I try to debug it on in or the emulator form eclipse. Any ideas? because it is impossible to error track for me now. Ive looked at tons of posts related to not being able to connect to the camera service but havent had any luck applying it to my circumstance.

**Side note:** Also the camera used to work fine and ran this exact app a few days ago with no troubles. My thinking is that it has something to do with eclipse. Since the app works perfectly on my phone when ran from the apk

**update:** I uninstalled eclipse and re-installed it and same error is still occurring. What is happening? This code works just not when I run it in eclipse ahhg

my LogCat:

```
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.fuchs.frontcam/com.fuchs.frontcam.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:258)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:220)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at com.fuchs.frontcam.MainActivity.initCamera(MainActivity.java:56)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at com.fuchs.frontcam.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:49)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
05-27 22:20:55.197: E/AndroidRuntime(419):  ... 12 more
```

Comment: its because there is no camera in emulator!! test on real device it should work

Comment: Are you checking if the target supports/has front facing camera?

Comment: @shoerat yes the target supports a front facing camera because my real device that I try to test it on from eclipse is the same device that the app runs perfectly on when I export as an apk and run it on it

Comment: I suppose your comp has a (web)cam? Or did you choose emulated option for the camera?

Comment: I chose the web cam option

Comment: I just installed the android studio ide to see if that would solve the problem and it dosent either, I just exported the project as an apk and it worked perfect though when I ran it on my phone after I installed the apk